# angularjs: ng-model double object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to achieve a double nested object. (Example Below)
The Problem is that my current Code is generating a Array inside a Object.

```
<div ng-if="newResultUnits()" ng-repeat="set in sets" ng-model="newexercise.sets[$index]">
                    <label>Set {{$index+1}}</label>
                    <label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="text" ng-repeat="resultUnit in newResultUnits()" ng-model="newexercise.sets[$parent.$index][$index].value" placeholder="{{resultUnit.name}}">
                        </label>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Example (the name attr is added later):

```
{  
       name:"MultiTest",
       sets:[  
          { 
             0:{ 
                value:"10",
                name:"Kg"
             },
             1:{ 
                value:"10",
                name:"Wdh"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

This is how it should be: (Please note the doubble `[[` and the missing `0:`)

```
    {
      "name": "MultiTest",
      "sets": [
        [
          {
            "value": "10",
            "name": "Kg"
          },
          {
            "value": "10",
            "name": "Wdh"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```

Im sorry if I mixedup Array and Object.. Thanks!

Comment: What is sets originally?

Comment: Hi dfsq, thanks for your answer. $scope.sets is just a empty array. items will be pushed to it when the user wants to add more sets. simple dynamic form :) Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need properly initialize your data structures. So in controller begin with

```
$scope.newexercise = { sets: [] };
```

So Angular knows that you want `$scope.newexercise` to be an array. Then in template use ngInit on every inner loop `ng-init="newexercise.sets[$parent.$index] = []"`:

```
<div ng-repeat="set in sets">
    <label>Set {{$index+1}}</label>
    <label>
        <label>
            <input type="text" 
                   ng-repeat="resultUnit in newResultUnits()" 
                   ng-init="newexercise.sets[$parent.$index] = []" 
                   ng-model="newexercise.sets[$parent.$index][$index].value" 
                   placeholder="{{resultUnit.name}}">
        </label>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/s1rInT8rLg50ISsSVxyV?p=preview

Comment: That´s it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Here is one more variation if you plan to have more fields in inner repeat: http://plnkr.co/edit/OFpIPuGNgPGlPhZ3d1Qq